# I'm getting WinError 10060; might it be caused by a python thread visiting the server too frequently?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I use a Python thread to download data from APIs. I'm not sure how it gets to the server, but I set it to make no more than 1000 calls every minute. It works good most of the time, but occasionally I get **WinError 10060** (without modifying my code). Whenever this happens, I simply re-download and it typically works without issue.

When I contacted the API provider about the 10060 issue, they indicated it had nothing to do with their server and that it could be due to a Windows socket. They tell me to use Linux and test if I have the same problem, but this is too much work for me.

So, what is the problem, and is there a solution?

Comment: This is probably just a timeout exception. Try to use the function call that triggers that error inside a try-except block. Inside the except block, you can choose to ignore the error and try again (inside a while loop, for example). Maybe the server is too busy and the socket connection times out.

Comment: That’s it. The server is too busy. Dial down your usage, or use a connection pool.